# add icon in uitextfield - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add icon in textfield. [This is how my UI looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G9Gn.png) with code below

Im expecting my UI should look similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJaoI.png)

// creating view (holderView) to hold icon image(image) and add view to textField (txtEmail)

```
    let holderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 40, height: 40))

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

    let image = UIImage(named: "ic_lock_48pt")

    imageView.image = image

    holderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    holderView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.center = CGPoint(x: holderView.frame.size.width / 2, y: holderView.frame.size.height / 2)

    txtEmail.leftView = holderView
```

(**If im doing long process to fix this please let me know**)

so I wanted to add constraints programatically to fix and below is the code

```
    holderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: emailView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: emailView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 0.12, constant: 0)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: emailView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: emailView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

//I have txtEmail in another view (emailView) 
//Error while running any of two lines of code below

```
    emailView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint]) //or
   txtEmail.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

Kindly suugest me how to fix this

Comment: Dont use constrain programically just create one view and add one imageview that your icon and second your textfied its work smoothly.

Comment: and in your question you got output in image icon is different then you actually need .

Comment: code updated.let me know. what you think...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try his code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: -1, y: 0, width: 30, height: 40))
    let image = UIImage(named: "q.png")
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.6)
    imageView.image = image
    textfield.leftView = imageView

    textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.6).cgColor
    textfield.layer.borderWidth = 2

    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.6).cgColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textfield.layer.masksToBounds = true

 }
```

**Note:** You have to create an icon image similar to below image to achieve the effect.Its all about creating an icon and place it in a right position.hope this helps..

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Brother check the question before answer what he actually want .